# Ho to parse xml file to xlsx in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have a file xml like this (input):

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?\>
> <obs id="0"\>
> <dim name="Column1" value="a"/\>
> <dim name="Column2" value="b"/\>
> </obs\>
> <obs id="1">
> <dim name="Column1" value="tr"/\>
> <dim name="Column2" value="yu"/\>
> </obs\>
```

How can i do for parse in xlsx file?
i would like to have a xlsx file like this:

Column1|Column2
a      |b
tr     |yu

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | b |
| tr | yu |

Thanks a lot.
I've tried with other xml parser but i did not realised the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `BeautifulSoup` to parse the XML document + `pandas` to save the dataframe to CSV and/or Excel format:

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open("your_file.xml", "r") as f_in:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f_in.read(), "html.parser")  # <-- you can ignore the warning or use different parser, such as `xml`

all_data = []
for obs in soup.select("obs"):
    d = {}
    for dim in obs.select("dim[name][value]"):
        d[dim["name"]] = dim["value"]

    all_data.append(d)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)

df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

This prints:

```
  Column1 Column2
0       a       b
1      tr      yu
```

and saves `data.csv`.

---

Input file was:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<obs id="0">
<dim name="Column1" value="a" />
<dim name="Column2" value="b" />
</obs>
<obs id="1">
<dim name="Column1" value="tr" />
<dim name="Column2" value="yu" />
</obs>
```

Comment: This kind of XML structure throws failure, if you try to validate it.

Answer (score 2):

You need a well formed XML with only **one** `root element`, like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
  <obs id="0">
    <dim name="Column1" value="a"/>
    <dim name="Column2" value="b"/>
  </obs>
  <obs id="1">
    <dim name="Column1" value="tr"/>
    <dim name="Column2" value="yu"/>
  </obs>
</root>
```

You can parse this xml to columns and rows for a pandas *DataFrame* and write this *df* to a Excel sheet with pandas `ExcelWriter()`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

tree = ET.parse('Excel.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

columns = []
data = []
for elem in root.iter('dim'):
    if elem.get('name') not in columns:
        columns.append(elem.get('name'))
    if elem.get('name') == "Column1":
        c1 = elem.get('value')
    else:
        c2 = elem.get('value')
        row = (c1, c2)
        data.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
print(df)

with pd.ExcelWriter("Excel.xlsx") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer)
```

Result: [image: Excel]